# How to detect which element of datalist items is clicked?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, datalist

my webform app have a datalist in the updatepanel, and datalist contain:{imagebutton, label,label}. datalist is connected to bank. in imagebutton thumbs of images will be show. I want when a user clicked each imagebutton in datalist, original image will be shown. 
all data successfully shown in datalist but problem is after click on imagebutton. i cant continue.  how can I detect which imagebutton clicked? what is the its datasource? what is the text or datasource of labes that are in same cell?

please help me, my code is as blow:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>

<div class="content">          
        <div class="datashow">
            <asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server" BorderColor="#666666" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="2px" CellPadding="2" CellSpacing="2" Font-Size="Small"   RepeatDirection="Horizontal" CssClass="dl" HorizontalAlign="Center" RepeatColumns="5">                    
            <HeaderStyle BackColor="#333333" Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="Large" ForeColor="White"  HorizontalAlign="Center" Wrap="True" />                                                                                  
                <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:ImageButton  ID="imgbtn" runat="server"  ImageUrl='<%# Bind("imgtp","~/images/{0}") %>'  Width="100px" OnClick="imgbtn_Click" />
                <br />
                <b>Employee Name:</b>
                <asp:Label ID="lblCName" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("name") %>'></asp:Label>
                <br />
                <b>Designation:</b>
                <asp:Label ID="lblName" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("company") %>'></asp:Label>

            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:DataList>    

        </div>              
</div>

    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

and

```
protected void imgbtn_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    //how to detect which imagebtn clicked and what is its datasource?
}
```

Comment: Whats your observation? Is the code in `imgbtn_Click` executing?!

Comment: If you intend to be a good SO citizen, please make an attempt to "search" questions already posted which might be related to your issue before you post your question : http://stackoverflow.com/a/18522585/145682

Comment: how to find a div inside updatepanel but outside the button cell?

Comment: Try recursively iterating `UpdatePanel1.Controls`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `sender` is the button, it's   `NamingContainer` is the `DataListItem`:

```
protected void imgbtn_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    var imgbtn = (ImageButton)  sender;
    var item   = (DataListItem) imgbtn.NamingContainer;
    // the datasource is not available on postback, but you have all other controls
    var lblCName = (Label) item.FindControl("lblCName");
    string company = lblCName.Text;
}
```

You could also use the `ImageButton`'s [`CommandArgument`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.imagebutton.commandargument(v=vs.110).aspx) to store the ID or use a hidden control (`Visible=false` or `HiddenField`) to store it.

Comment: thank you, but sometime 45 item appear when i selected * from db, then how to findcontrol from 45 lblcname?

Comment: @Robert: with my code above you will always find the controls in the same item of the datalist which was clicked. Is that what you want? The `NamingContainer` always refers to the `DataListItem` of the control.

Comment: how to find a div inside updatepanel but outside the button cell?