# ASP.NET - Clicking on an image should redirect to a specific page with image url

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am basically making a website for my university project which is basically a photography&wallpapers site
I have saved images in folder(named as ImageStorage) and I am retrieving images through Image link from database
I have used datalist in my page(image-viewer.aspx) to show my all images as imagebutton. What I basically want is that when user clicks on an image it redirects to another page(image-detail.aspx)and also sends the url or id of that image so that I can use it to display that image on (image-detail.aspx) page

Here is my image_viewer.aspx code:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
<asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server" CellPadding="15" CellSpacing="10" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" GridLines="Both" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DataList1_SelectedIndexChanged" RepeatColumns="3" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" style="margin-left: 0px" >
<ItemTemplate>
<br />
<asp:ImageButton ID="Image1"  style="width:335px ;height:210px" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# Eval("ImagePath") %>' CommandName="imgClick"/>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
<br />
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:photo_stock_viewConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [ImageInfo1]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
<br />
</div>
</form>
```

HTML code in image_detail.aspx to show image:

```
<img class="img-fluid mt-4" src="ImageStorage/image-detail.jpg"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need code behind to handle the image click event

```
protected void DataList1_ItemCommand(object source, DataListCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "imgClick")
    {
       ImageButton btn = e.CommandSource as ImageButton;
       //Do what you need to do here
       string imgUrl = btn.ImageUrl;
       Response.Redirect(imgUrl,true);
}
```

If you need set more info like imageID, you also can use CommandArgument as parameter, set in html and get it from code behind
Here is the URL [how to know which image button I click in datalist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18522210/how-to-know-which-image-button-i-click-in-datalist)

Comment: how this will take me to another page? :/

Comment: You can easily use Response.Redirect(URL, true);

Comment: okay thanks it's working. Now how can I move an img path to a new page(image-detail.aspx) and display this image in it I shall be very thankful !!

Comment: <a href='<%# "image-detail.aspx?ImagePath="+Eval("ImagePath")%>'>                           I used this to move to other page instead of ImageButton now  how can I move an img path to a new page(image-detail.aspx) and display this image in it

Comment: You can use <a href='image-detail.aspx?imagePath=<%# Eval("ImagePath")%>'>link</a>